# Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type: Avoid "Optional()"

Tags: xcode, swift

I've saved player skills in NSUserDefaults as a dictionary but when I want to access it, xcode says "cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type". When I remove "!" it writes out "Optional (1)" where I want to get rid of "Optional()". How can I just write out "1"?

```
if let playerDic = defaults.objectForKey("Player") as? [String: Int] {
    lbLevel.setText(String(playerDic!["level"]))
}
```

turns into

```
"Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type"
```

where

```
if let playerDic = defaults.objectForKey("Player") as? [String: Int] {
    lbLevel.setText(String(playerDic["level"]))
}
```

turns into

```
Optional(1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've already unwrapped playerDic in the if let binding. Just drop the force unwrap like the error message tells you.

```
if let playerDic = defaults.objectForKey("Player") as? [String: Int] {
    lbLevel.setText(String(playerDic["level"]))
}
```

**Update** 
Sorry just saw your update. So playerDic isn't an optional, but the values returned for keys are optionals. If you ask for the value for a key that is not in the dictionary you will get an optional with the value of nil.

```
if let 
      playerDic = defaults.objectForKey("Player") as? [String: Int],
      level = playerDic["level"]   {
    lbLevel.setText("\(level)")
}
```

Here you can bind multiple values in a single if let. Also, you can use String(level) or use string interpolation "(level)" depending on what you prefer.

Comment: But then it prints out "Optional(1)" where I just want "1"

Comment: did you do `String(playerDic["level"]!)`  note the ! at the end

Comment: I would not do what KnightOfDragon suggests. There is no need to force unwrap as you can safely bind the value in your existing if statement. What KnightOfDragon suggests will crash when you try to access a key that is not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

### The bang at the end (!) :

You are trying to pass an optional to a method that does not receive `nil`: `String(optional)` to solve this just unwrap it with (!) at the end `String(optional!)`:

```
if let playerDic = defaults.objectForKey("Player") as? [String: Int] {
    lbLevel.setText(String(playerDic["level"]!)) <-- the bang at the end
}
```