# Cannot avoid optional() for string print statements?

Tags: swift

I have a data struct which contains some string parameters. The struct is below:

```
struct pulledMessage{
    var convoWithUserID: String
    var convoWithUserName: String
}
```

I have a function which assigns a value to variables based on the values within a particular `pulledMessage`. For some more complicated, out-of-the-scope-of-the-question, reasons, these values come from `[pulledMessage]` array. The `pulledMessage` always changes in the actual function but for illustration purposes I will write it as a constant:

```
var messageArray = [pulledMessage]()


func assignValues(){
    messageArray.append(pulledMessage(convoWithUserID: "abc123", convoWithUserName: "Kevin"))
    let convoWithUserID = messageArray[0].convoWithUserID
    let convoWithUserName = messageArray[0].convoWithUserName
    print(convoWithUserID) //returns optional("abc123")
    print(convoWithUserName) // returns optional("Kevin")
}
```

I have tried adding `!` to unwrap the values in different ways:

```
messageArray[0]!.convoWithUserID
```

This tells gives me an error that I cannot unwrap a non-optional type of `pulledMessage`.

```
messageArray[0].convoWithUserID!
```

This gives me an error that I cannot unwrap a non-optional type of String.
[This stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785303/cannot-force-unwrap-value-of-non-optional-type-avoid-optional) suggests utilizing `if let` to get rid of the optional:

```
if let convoWithUserIDCheck = messageArray[0].convoWithUserID{
    convoWithUserID = convoWithUserIDCheck
}
```

This gives me a warning that there is no reason to do `if let` with a non-optional type of string. I have no idea how to get it to stop returning the values wrapped by optional().

**Update: The more complicated, complete code**

The SQL Database functions:

```
class FMDBManager: NSObject {
    static let shared: FMDBManager = FMDBManager()


let databaseFileName = "messagesBetweenUsers.sqlite"

var pathToDatabase: String!

var database: FMDatabase!

override init() {
    super.init()

    let documentsDirectory = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString) as String
    pathToDatabase = documentsDirectory.appending("/\(databaseFileName)")
}
func loadMessageData(){//will need a struct to load the data into a struct


    if openDatabase(){
        let query = "select * from messages order by messageNumber asc"
        do{
            print(database)
            let results: FMResultSet = try database.executeQuery(query, values: nil)

            while results.next(){

                let message = pulledMessage(convoWithUserID: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "convoWithUserID")), convoWithUserName: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "convoWithUserName")), messageString: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "messageString")), senderID: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "senderID")), timeSent: String(describing: results.string(forColumn: "timeSent")), messageNumber: Int(results.int(forColumn: "messageNumber")))
                if messagesPulled == nil{
                    messagesPulled = [pulledMessage]()
                }
                messagesPulled.append(message)
                print("The message that we have pulled are \(message)")
            }

        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        database.close()
    }


}
}
```

Running the population of the data at the onset of app launch:

```
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
//        if FMDBManager.shared.createDatabase() {
//            FMDBManager.shared.insertMessageData()
//        }else{
//            print("Not a chance, sonny")
//            FMDBManager.shared.insertMessageData()
//        }
        FMDBManager.shared.loadMessageData()
    }
```

Organizing the SQL data in order:

```
struct pulledMessage{//global struct
    var convoWithUserID: String
    var convoWithUserName: String
    var messageString: String
    var senderID: String
    var timeSent: String
    var messageNumber: Int
}

var messagesPulled: [pulledMessage]!

var messageConvoDictionary = [String: [pulledMessage]]()
//For the individual message convos
    var fullUnorderedMessageArray = [[pulledMessage]]()
    var fullOrderedMessageArray = [[pulledMessage]]()

    //For the message table
    var unorderedLastMessageArray = [pulledMessage]()
    var orderedLastMessageArray = [pulledMessage]()




    //For the table messages... FROM HERE..........................................
    func organizeSQLData(messageSet: [pulledMessage]){
        var i = 0
        var messageUserID = String()
        while i < messageSet.count{
            if (messageSet[i]).convoWithUserID != messageUserID{
                print("It wasn't equal")
                print(messageSet[i])
                messageUserID = messageSet[i].convoWithUserID
                if messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID] != nil{
                    messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID]?.append(messageSet[i])
                }else{
                    messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID] = []
                    messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID]?.append(messageSet[i])
                }
                i = i + 1
            }else{
                messageConvoDictionary[messageUserID]?.append(messageSet[i])
                i = i + 1
            }
        }

    }


    func getLastMessages(messageSet: [String:[pulledMessage]]){

        for (_, messages) in messageSet{
            let orderedMessages = messages.sorted(by:{ $0.timeSent.compare($1.timeSent) == .orderedAscending})
            let finalMessage = orderedMessages[0]
            unorderedLastMessageArray.append(finalMessage)
        }
        print(unorderedLastMessageArray)
    }

    func orderLastMessage(messageSet: [pulledMessage]){
        orderedLastMessageArray = messageSet.sorted(by:{ $0.timeSent.compare($1.timeSent) == .orderedDescending})
        messagesListTableView.reloadData()
        print("It wasn't\(orderedLastMessageArray)")
    }


    func getMessagesReady(){//for observer type function calls
        organizeSQLData(messageSet: messagesPulled)
        getLastMessages(messageSet: messageConvoDictionary)
        orderLastMessage(messageSet: unorderedLastMessageArray)
        //This one is for the individual full convos for if user clicks on a cell... its done last because its not required for the page to show up
        orderedFullMessageConvos(messageSet: messageConvoDictionary)
        let openedMessageConversation = fullOrderedMessageArray[(indexPath.row)]//not placed in its appropriate location, but it is just used to pass the correct array (actually goes in a prepareforSegue)

    }
     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
           getMessagesReady()
        }
```

Then segue to the new controller (passing `openedMessageConversation` to `messageConvo`) and run this process on a button click:

```
let newMessage = pulledMessage(convoWithUserID: messageConvo[0].convoWithUserID, convoWithUserName: messageConvo[0].convoWithUserName, messageString: commentInputTextfield.text!, senderID: (PFUser.current()?.objectId)!, timeSent: String(describing: Date()), messageNumber: 0)
            messageConvo.append(newMessage)
            let newMessageSent = PFObject(className: "UserMessages")
            newMessageSent["convoWithUserID"] = newMessage.convoWithUserID
            newMessageSent["convoWithUserName"] = newMessage.convoWithUserName
            newMessageSent["messageString"] = newMessage.messageString
            newMessageSent["senderID"] = newMessage.senderID
            let acl = PFACL()
            acl.getPublicWriteAccess = true
            acl.getPublicReadAccess = true
            acl.setWriteAccess(true, for: PFUser.current()!)
            acl.setReadAccess(true, for: PFUser.current()!)
            newMessageSent.acl = acl
            newMessageSent.saveInBackground()
```

It is the `newMessageSent["convoWithUserID"]` and `newMessageSent["convoWithUserName"]` that read with the optional() in the database.

Comment: I just copied your code into an Xcode 9 Swift Playground and I do not get the "optional" in the print output. It just shows the expected string value. Did you copy and paste real code into your question?

Comment: try var convoWithUserID: String! maybe?

Comment: @koropok No, do not do that. That's an optional. The OP doesn't have and doesn't need an optional.

Comment: @rmaddy ah i see

Comment: @rmaddy I did not paste exact code as it is significantly more complicated (involving passing data between viewControllers, though this is not the source of the issue because even the passed data has the same issue before being passed, and saving to a database)

Comment: @AlekPiasecki The code you posted does not reproduce the issue. In order for anyone to help you, you will need to update your question with code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy I will post the full associated code, though it is extensive. One moment

Comment: Narrow your code down to a minimal set of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy I have pasted all code which I believe may be relevant to the problem

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the reason for this stems from the function run from `loadMessageData`. The use of `String(describing: results.string(forColumn:)` requires an unwrapping of `results.String(forColumn:)!`. This issue propagated throughout the data modification for the whole app and caused the `optional()` wrapping for the print statements that I was seeing.

Comment: Indeed – `String(describing:)` is almost *never* what you want.

Comment: How do I avoid this if I want to save the values as strings while they may be something like `dates` or `ints`?

Comment: Depends. What should happen if it's nil? Should it print a placeholder value, or bail out?

Comment: If the former: `let string = optionalString ?? "Default Value"`

Comment: If the latter: `guard let string = optionalString else { throw someError }`

Comment: Avoid the force-unwrap operator `!` unless you absolutely, positively, know it will never be nil. The most common legitimate use of `!` is when you are dealing with xib/storyboard files in which you know certain things will be set up a certain way at runtime, and it's a programming error if they aren't. But the use of `!` should be *rare.*

Comment: The main "problem" of `String(describing:)` is with optionals. As an example: `let x: Int? = 3 ; let s = String(describing: x)` creates the string "Optional(3)" which makes you *think* that this is an optional string, but it isn't. – Unfortunately, the compiler suggests String(describing:) as a Fix-it for `String(someOptional)`

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, I currently use `!` extensively in my app to avoid this optional() printouts (and very often for `label.text`). Does the `?? "Default Value"` method adequately handle the removal of `optional()` if the value is not `nil`? ie. if my value exists, would its `.text` if used in a label contain the `optional()` wrap?

Comment: @AlekPiasecki If the value is not `nil`, it will print exactly what it would have printed if you had used `!`. If it is nil, it prints your placeholder (I usually use `"(nil)"`) instead of crashing. It's a win/win all around.